# Convert C# lambda function to VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda, idatareader

I have this function that maps a IDataReader to a class. It is obviously written in C#. My co-worker wants to use the same method in his code, but he is writing  in VB.net. Basically I am having difficulty rewriting this due to the Lambda expressions used in C#. He is running .Net 3.5.

Can anyone help me?

```
private Func<IDataReader, ScanItem> resultMapper = r =>
    {
        var si = new ScanItem()
        {
            StoreGroupCode = r.ToInt32("GRP_CDE"),
            StoreCode = r.ToInt32("STOR_CDE"),
            EventNumber = r.ToInt32("EVENT_NUM"),
            AreaNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_CTL_AREA_CDE"),
            LabelNumber = r.ToInt32("LBL_NUM"),
            ScanType = r.ToString("INV_SCAN_TYP_IND"),
            SequenceNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_SCAN_SEQ_NUM"),
            UPC = r.ToLong("VEN_UPC_NUM"),
            ActualQuantity = r.ToLong("ACT_CNT_QTY")
        };

        return si;
    };
```

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer that helps you as accepted, and you should do the same for your oher questions (even if you gave the best answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC VB.NET in .NET 3.5 doesn't support anonymous functions with body. Your co-worker using VB.NET will have to define a function containing this code and in the lambda expression use this function. Now, this being said, it's not really necessary to use a complex function with body in this case and this code could be simplified to:

```
private Func<IDataReader, ScanItem> resultMapper = r => new ScanItem
{
    StoreGroupCode = r.ToInt32("GRP_CDE"),
    StoreCode = r.ToInt32("STOR_CDE"),
    EventNumber = r.ToInt32("EVENT_NUM"),
    AreaNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_CTL_AREA_CDE"),
    LabelNumber = r.ToInt32("LBL_NUM"),
    ScanType = r.ToString("INV_SCAN_TYP_IND"),
    SequenceNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_SCAN_SEQ_NUM"),
    UPC = r.ToLong("VEN_UPC_NUM"),
    ActualQuantity = r.ToLong("ACT_CNT_QTY")
};
```

which normally if my VB.NET isn't too rusty should look something along the lines of:

```
Private resultMapper As Func(Of IDataReader, ScanItem) = Function(r) New ScanItem() With { _
    .StoreGroupCode = r.ToInt32("GRP_CDE"), _
    .StoreCode = r.ToInt32("STOR_CDE"), _
    .EventNumber = r.ToInt32("EVENT_NUM"), _
    .AreaNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_CTL_AREA_CDE"), _
    .LabelNumber = r.ToInt32("LBL_NUM"), _
    .ScanType = r.ToString("INV_SCAN_TYP_IND"), _
    .SequenceNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_SCAN_SEQ_NUM"), _
    .UPC = r.ToLong("VEN_UPC_NUM"), _
    .ActualQuantity = r.ToLong("ACT_CNT_QTY") _
}
```

Comment: The poster doesn't really need the body for his anonymous method. It can EASILY be simplified into a single line....

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
Private resultMapper As Func(Of IDataReader, ScanItem) = Function (r) _
    New ScanItem() With { _
        .StoreGroupCode = r.ToInt32("GRP_CDE"), _
        .StoreCode = r.ToInt32("STOR_CDE"), _
        .EventNumber = r.ToInt32("EVENT_NUM"), _
        .AreaNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_CTL_AREA_CDE"), _
        .LabelNumber = r.ToInt32("LBL_NUM"), _
        .ScanType = r.ToString("INV_SCAN_TYP_IND"), _
        .SequenceNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_SCAN_SEQ_NUM"), _
        .UPC = r.ToLong("VEN_UPC_NUM"), _
        .ActualQuantity = r.ToLong("ACT_CNT_QTY") _
    }
```

In newer versions of VB you can omit the annoying explicit line continuations (`_`).

Comment: `Func<IDataReader, ScanItem>` should probably be `Func(Of IDataReader, ScanItem)`.

Comment: How does this compile? You have resultMapper in the declaration twice!

Comment: @Chris Typo. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and it had no problem converting the code:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

The only thing to beware of is VB.NET 9 (VS 2008/.NET 3.5) doesn't support multi-line lambda expressions. So you can't split it into 2 lines.

So...

```
Private resultMapper As Func(Of IDataReader, ScanItem) = Function(r) New ScanItem() With { _
    .StoreGroupCode = r.ToInt32("GRP_CDE"), _
    .StoreCode = r.ToInt32("STOR_CDE"), _
    .EventNumber = r.ToInt32("EVENT_NUM"), _
    .AreaNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_CTL_AREA_CDE"), _
    .LabelNumber = r.ToInt32("LBL_NUM"), _
    .ScanType = r.ToString("INV_SCAN_TYP_IND"), _
    .SequenceNumber = r.ToInt32("INV_SCAN_SEQ_NUM"), _
    .UPC = r.ToLong("VEN_UPC_NUM"), _
    .ActualQuantity = r.ToLong("ACT_CNT_QTY") _
}
```

Comment: The automatic converter is a bit confused. The `Key` keyword doesn’t belong here, since this isn’t an anonymous class.